# grails can't find view from plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, gsp

I'm trying to write a grails plugin that can view files. Actually, I'm just trying to upgrade this one here... https://github.com/intelligrape/File-Viewer-Grails-Plugin to grails4, and get it working in my app.

Anyway, after I get it working in the app, I visit http://localhost:8080/file/index and I get this error:

```
URI
/file/index
Class
javax.servlet.ServletException
Message
Could not resolve view with name '/plugins/file-explorer-0.1/file/fileList' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
```

This occurs when the controller does this...

```
def index(String filePath) {
    Map model = [locations: fileLocations.locations]
    // blah blah
    render(view: "/file/fileList", model: model, plugin: 'fileExplorer')
}
```

The render() method is called (I checked in the debugger). I also tried removing the plugin: parameter, but it made no difference.

Now if I run the plugin as a standalone app (by going to that folder, and running "grails run-app", then it works as expected, and http://localhost:8080/file/index renders the view as one would expect.

This all leads me to believe that the plugin is basicly working and installed into my app EXCEPT the view component, which for whatever reason cannot find the views from a plugin.

If you want to know what the source looks like, it's basically what you see here:.. https://github.com/intelligrape/File-Viewer-Grails-Plugin   Except I've renamed it from FileViewer to FileExplorer.

I'm using grails 4.1.0.M5   I don't know if it could be a bug in this version or what.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I should have had

```
plugin: 'filexplorer'
```

instead of

```
plugin: 'fileExplorer'
```

I could have sworn I tried this already. I guess the thing is it can be confusing which name to use where as far as plugins, as in the build.gradle name, the name in the *Plugin.groovy, the name in settings.gradle, the package name etc. Anyway, somehow I screwed up.